# Getting data from column with range of values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle

I want to get data on particular range of column in a table. but the data is of type varchar.

Suppose i have table student and a column is ID and the value in the ID is as AB12346854, and I need to find all the students in range of id AB12346854  to DE12548847 I tried using the query as

```
select * from students where id>='AB12346854' and id<='DE12548847'.
```

I am getting rows with id value as null .( id is not primary key)

Comment: Are you sure you are getting null? Perhaps you are getting empty string.

Comment: yes getting null value. and one more thing i missed  that is there any way to get data if i received id as DE12548847 and AB12346854 (i.e to get data between DE12548847  and AB12346854)

Comment: What you tried mostly makes sense. Perhaps if you post the exact SQL we can find the mistake. Also, you can use `BETWEEN` for this type of test. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/735ad/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

`select * from students where id BETWEEN 'AB12346854' AND 'DE12548847'`

It works for strings too.

Answer (score 0):

select * from test where ID >= 'AA0000001' and ID <= 'DD0000004'

tis is working perfectly fine... even if u ve null values for your ID column